# WiFi not working in new user account (WiFi works under default Pi account)

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I have created a new user account as I dont want to use the default Pi account.

Now under my new user account, the WiFi dongle isnt detected (in wpa_gui program the Adapter and Network dropdown lists are blank). There is a message shown:

```
could not get status from wpa_supplicant
```

However under the default Pi account it is detected and WiFi works. What could be the problem?

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue. Could you run `groups USERNAME` and post the output?

Comment: The output is `user : user` (where user is my username)

Comment: That would be probably your issue. Your user doesn't have permissions to access network stuff. Lemme finish answering another question and get back to you.

Comment: Run `sudo usermod -a -G netdev USER` and reboot and then try out the WiFi.

Comment: Glad to help! I'll post that as answer so it can be marked. We're trying to get the site Q:A ratio and % answered up, so if you ask a question, don't forget to, if one solves your issue, mark it as answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was solved in the comments, the OP's account didn't have the group permissions required for the networking.

He ran `sudo usermod -a -G netdev USER` and then rebooted and the issue was solved.